# How do I connect with other xml file xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have two XML files using the XML data processing files How do I connect them to each other?

Example:

members.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<member id="1" username="selahattin" name="Selahattin" surname="Yüksel"/>
<member id="2" username="test" name="John" surname="Bravo"/>
</Data>
```

comments.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<member id="1" username="selahattin" comment="Hi, stackoverflow"/>
<member id="2" username="test" comment="Hello world!"/>
</Data>
```

Using two XML files in the username field of the data How do you want to take this?

username==username

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What do you mean, "connect them to each other"? Also which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am using 4.0. I will list the data by connecting the two fields in the XML file such as a user name SQL inner join.

Comment: Please show what your expected result is. And please show how you tried to solve the problem. We won't do your work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not speak English. Can you give an example of how I can do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this site does require a reasonable proficiency in English. Perhaps you can find someone to translate for you.

Answer (score 0):

here is one method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            ds1.ReadXml(FILENAME1);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            ds2.ReadXml(FILENAME2);

            var results = from dataRows1 in ds1.Tables["member"].AsEnumerable()
                                     join dataRows2 in ds2.Tables["member"].AsEnumerable()
                                     on dataRows1.Field<string>("id") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("id") into ps
                                     select dataRows1;
            DataTable combinedTable = results.CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: I did not look like but comment field.

Code: http://hizliresim.com/3DjM19
Output: http://hizliresim.com/8g2591